# Count total no. of downloads of a file from document library

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, document-library

I'm trying to make a portlet which shows most downloaded files from document library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tracked "readCount" attribute from the table DLFileEntry table. But how to retrieve value of readCount?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryServiceUtil`

Specifically

```
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryServiceUtil.getFileEntry(long groupId, long folderId, java.lang.String name)
```

You will get DLFileEntry so

```
DLFileEntry dlfe = com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryServiceUtil.getFileEntry(my-group-id, folder-id, name);
dlfe.getReadCount();
```

will get you what you want.